# Script only loading directly after clearing the cache, but cant get found after second reload

Tags: magento2, script, static-content, magento2.3.4, symlinks

I am using the extension Aheadworks_Wbtab. I don't know whats going on. If I flush the cache and reload then the slider shows and works fine. But if I reload again, then the slider dissapears and I get this error logged in my browser console:

> mixins.js:245 GET
>   https://www.example.com/pub/static/version1584092638/frontend/company/base/de_DE/Aheadworks_Wbtab/js/aw-wbtab-ajax.js
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 404 req.load @ require.js:1895 ... Show 268 more
>   frames
>
> main.js:37 Error: Script error for: Aheadworks_Wbtab/js/aw-wbtab-ajax
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
>       at makeError (require.js:166)
>       at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)

So I checked if the file was created in `pub/static` and it is there (as a symlink):

> **pub/static/frontend/company/base/de_DE/Aheadworks_Wbtab/js/aw-wbtab-ajax.js**
>   -> /home/company/example.com/vendor/aheadworks/module-wbtab/view/frontend/web/js/**aw-wbtab-ajax.js**

I also opened the file and it has content.

How can I fix it and what causes the bug?

Only this extension from Aheadworks causes this bug, all other extensions from Amasty work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I executed "**grunt clean**" and flushed the cache again. Now it seems to work suddenly.

Comment: This sort of thing is why I stopped using grunt and only use the built in static content deploy command to build the theme

Comment: It has nothing to do with grunt. Grunt is a great helper, otherwise your would have to manually do alot of tasks, e.g. instead of `grunt clean` i would have to manually delete some folders.

Comment: Unfortunately in my experience theme inheritance and static content generation doesnt work the same when using grunt. Mainly permission issues. But if it works for you then that's great.

Comment: Plus https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7231

Comment: Maybe your server is not setup correctly

Comment: Disregarding the magento issue reported above possibly. But what is the correct setup? I work for an agency which uses cPanel servers, Plesk, docker and Amazon AWS. I work with both apache and nginx. I work with various caching strategies enabled. I've worked on various zero downtime deployment strategies using various techniques. I'm always seeing different behaviour because the platforms I work on are fundamentally different.